# Selecting Cell in PivotTable produces Sheet1. How can I get this action to create a named tab?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

When selecting a cell in a pivot table you can double click to open a sequentially named tab (Sheet1, Sheet2, etc).
This application of sequantially named tabs is causing my VBA to error out as the tab # changes during routine use of the xls as a whole (i.e. I may run the code more than once without closing the file).

Is there a way to create a named tab each time I double click on a PivotTable cell?

Here is my existing code:

```
Range("E7").Select
Selection.ShowDetail = True  'double clicking PivotTable that creates the 
                             '"Sheet_" below
Sheets("Sheet3").Select      'this and the next line are just me renaming 
                             'tab what I would like the tab to be named 
                             'upon double clicking the PivotTable
Sheets("Sheet3").Name = "Obsolete"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this workbook event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    On Error Resume Next
    If (Sh.ListObjects.Count = 1) Then Sh.Name = "Obsolete"
End Sub
```

Any time a sheet is added that already has a table in it (i.e. from double-clicking a pivot table) it will be renamed to "Obsolete". On error resume next is to prevent errors if the name is already taken - macro will just do nothing instead.

Comment: Would I be allowed to string two of these together? i.e. one tab for obsolete and one for excess?